How to move camera poses in colmap?
I have images.txt file with 2 records:
    1 0.01733147722376776 0.37417104773651677 0.042901493532558815 -0.9262046797472335 2.0 2.0 2.0 0 img0.jpeg

    2 -0.2 0.5 0.04 0.1 1.34681217 1.08815916 0.04479532 0 img0.jpeg
    


I try to create a new camera position centred where the camera 1 is, but rotated in the same way as camera 2.
My steps are:

get centre of the camera 1
After colmap docs the camera center is located at -R^t * T
from scipy.spatial.transform import Rotation as R

def compute_camera_center(quaternion, translation):
   rotation = R.from_quat(quaternion)
   R_matrix = rotation.as_matrix()
   camera_center = -R_matrix.T @ translation
   return camera_center

compute_camera_center([0.01733147722376776,
                       0.37417104773651677,
                       0.042901493532558815,
                       -0.9262046797472335], 
                      [-2.68882953, -2.17631834, -0.18394084])
# result array([ 1.90907645,  2.4155578 , -1.58761067])


get a translation vector for camera 2 quaternion and camera 1 center
This is inverting previous equation
from scipy.spatial.transform import Rotation as R

def compute_new_translation(quaternion, camera_center):
   rotation = R.from_quat(quaternion)
   R_matrix = rotation.as_matrix()
   new_translation = -R_matrix @ camera_center
   return new_translation

compute_new_translation([ 1.90907645,  2.4155578 , -1.58761067], [-0.2, 0.5, 0.04, 0.1])
# result array([ 3.38416821, -0.11275296, -0.7312266 ])



So the final file with all 3 cameras looks like:
    1 0.01733147722376776 0.37417104773651677 0.042901493532558815 -0.9262046797472335 2.0 2.0 2.0 0 img0.jpeg

    2 -0.2 0.5 0.04 0.1 1.34681217 1.08815916 0.04479532 0 img0.jpeg
    
    3 -0.2 0.5 0.04 0.1 3.38416821 -0.11275296 -0.7312266 0 img1.png
    

But the third camera ends up being located somewhere else then where camera 1 is.

Does anyone knows how to compute translation verctor for the camera 3, so it has rotation of camera 2, but is located where camera 1 is?

